# Wireless problem with Intel WiFi Link 5100

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, drivers, kubuntu

I'm using Kubuntu and I've problems connecting to Wifi since I tried to update the system a week ago. 
I tried installing drivers several times but nothing changed. Now I'm trying again with a fresh installation but it's not working. 
I need to know exactly what the problem is. (I can connect to the network with a cable)

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 12 Aug 2016 19:03 CEST +0200

Booted last: 12 Aug 2016 18:53 CEST +0200

Script from: 08 Jul 2016 02:16 UTC +0000


##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.19.0-66-generic #74-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 19 15:07:04 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Plasma

##### lspci #############################

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 [8086:4232]
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN [8086:1321]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

08:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1698] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:029f]
    Kernel driver in use: tg3

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bc2:231a Seagate RSS LLC 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 046d:c51b Logitech, Inc. V220 Cordless Optical Mouse for Notebooks
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 05ca:18a1 Ricoh Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 08ff:2810 AuthenTec, Inc. AES2810
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 413c:8158 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Touchpad / Trackstick
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 413c:8157 Dell Computer Corp. Integrated Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

dell_wmi               16384  0 
sparse_keymap          16384  1 dell_wmi
dell_laptop            16384  0 
iwldvm                237568  0 
dcdbas                 16384  1 dell_laptop
mac80211              733184  1 iwldvm
iwlwifi               200704  1 iwldvm
cfg80211              548864  3 iwlwifi,mac80211,iwldvm
wmi                    20480  1 dell_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>  
          inet addr:192.168.1.129  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF1]>/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:170014 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:91541 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:253509876 (253.5 MB)  TX bytes:6799755 (6.7 MB)
          Interrupt:17 

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    1024   0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search Home

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       647     1  0 18:54 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Broadcom Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         tg3
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.137
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               sb v2.17
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:08:00.0/net/eth0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       eth0
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Conexión cableada 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       9ce27574-68f9-4aac-9535-0a1e7cc9eec4
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     100 Mb/s
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{0}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   9ce27574-68f9-4aac-9535-0a1e7cc9eec4 | Conexión cableada 1
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = 192.168.1.129/24, gw = 192.168.1.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             87.216.1.65
IP4.DNS[2]:                             87.216.1.66
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          Home
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        network_number = 192.168.1.0
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        expiry = 1471280358
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        domain_name = Home
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 0.0.0.0
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       broadcast_address = 192.168.1.255
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       routers = 192.168.1.1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 259200
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       ip_address = 192.168.1.129
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       domain_name_servers = 87.216.1.65 87.216.1.66
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.1.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ip = fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF1]>/64, gw = ::

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        WiFi Link 5100 (AGN)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         iwlwifi
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.19.0-66-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               8.83.5.1 build 33692
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         42 (The supplicant is now available)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.1/0000:04:00.0/net/wlan0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: 
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WEP:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA:                    yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.WPA2:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.TKIP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.CCMP:                   yes
WIFI-PROPERTIES.AP:                     no
WIFI-PROPERTIES.ADHOC:                  yes

SSID                BSSID              MODE   CHAN  FREQ      RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY   ACTIVE  * 
Nandoorange         <MAC 'Nandoorange' [AN1]>  Infra  8     2447 MHz  54 Mbit/s  40      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
MOVISTAR_PLUS_E78A  <MAC 'MOVISTAR_PLUS_E78A' [AC1]>  Infra  104   5520 MHz  54 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA2       no        
Thom_D0042134       <MAC 'Thom_D0042134' [AN3]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  27      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2  no        
Orange-6B74         <MAC 'Orange-6B74' [AN4]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2  no        
MOVISTAR_5DF8       <MAC 'MOVISTAR_5DF8' [AN5]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA2       no        
VodafoneG458        <MAC 'VodafoneG458' [AN6]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  32      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
MOVISTAR_E78A       <MAC 'MOVISTAR_E78A' [AN7]>  Infra  6     2437 MHz  54 Mbit/s  34      ▂▄__  WPA2       no        
JAZZTEL_DD5B        <MAC 'JAZZTEL_DD5B' [AN8]>  Infra  1     2412 MHz  54 Mbit/s  100     ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2  no        
MOVISTAR_AC7D       <MAC 'MOVISTAR_AC7D' [AC2]>  Infra  11    2462 MHz  54 Mbit/s  22      ▂___  WPA1       no        

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Madrid (based on set time zone)

country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, NO-IR
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-IR
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), (N/A), NO-IR

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

wlan0     32 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz
          Channel 36 : 5.18 GHz
          Channel 40 : 5.2 GHz
          Channel 44 : 5.22 GHz
          Channel 48 : 5.24 GHz
          Channel 52 : 5.26 GHz
          Channel 56 : 5.28 GHz
          Channel 60 : 5.3 GHz
          Channel 64 : 5.32 GHz
          Channel 100 : 5.5 GHz
          Channel 104 : 5.52 GHz
          Channel 108 : 5.54 GHz
          Channel 112 : 5.56 GHz
          Channel 116 : 5.58 GHz
          Channel 120 : 5.6 GHz
          Channel 124 : 5.62 GHz
          Channel 128 : 5.64 GHz
          Channel 132 : 5.66 GHz
          Channel 136 : 5.68 GHz
          Channel 140 : 5.7 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

Sorry, try again.
lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

Channel occupancy:

      1   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
      1   APs on   Frequency:5.52 GHz (Channel 104)

wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'MOVISTAR_PLUS_E78A' [AC1]>
                    Channel:104
                    Frequency:5.52 GHz (Channel 104)
                    Quality=21/70  Signal level=-89 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"MOVISTAR_PLUS_E78A"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000004f5be810db
                    Extra: Last beacon: 1684ms ago
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
          Cell 02 - Address: <MAC 'MOVISTAR_AC7D' [AC2]>
                    Channel:11
                    Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
                    Quality=23/70  Signal level=-87 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"MOVISTAR_AC7D"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=00002601123af183
                    Extra: Last beacon: 6092ms ago
                    IE: WPA Version 1
                        Group Cipher : TKIP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK

##### module infos ######################

[iwldvm]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-66-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/dvm/iwldvm.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi Link AGN driver for Linux
srcversion:     734B867FAAD13922F696215
depends:        iwlwifi,mac80211,cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-66-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A6:7F:A1:0F:B1:52:23:8E:81:45:C8:5E:D3:90:DE:D3:2B:0E:A5:43
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           force_cam:force continuously aware mode (no power saving at all) (bool)

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-66-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     A1851295567B306D1C939BC
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-66-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A6:7F:A1:0F:B1:52:23:8E:81:45:C8:5E:D3:90:DE:D3:2B:0E:A5:43
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[iwlwifi]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-66-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
license:        GPL
author:         Copyright(c) 2003- 2014 Intel Corporation <ilw@linux.intel.com>
version:        in-tree:
description:    Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
firmware:       iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3165-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
firmware:       iwlwifi-8000-10.ucode
srcversion:     884420C3D4A6AC329614AEA
depends:        cfg80211
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-66-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A6:7F:A1:0F:B1:52:23:8E:81:45:C8:5E:D3:90:DE:D3:2B:0E:A5:43
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           swcrypto:using crypto in software (default 0 [hardware]) (int)
parm:           11n_disable:disable 11n functionality, bitmap: 1: full, 2: disable agg TX, 4: disable agg RX, 8 enable agg TX (uint)
parm:           amsdu_size_8K:enable 8K amsdu size (default 0) (int)
parm:           fw_restart:restart firmware in case of error (default true) (bool)
parm:           antenna_coupling:specify antenna coupling in dB (default: 0 dB) (int)
parm:           wd_disable:Disable stuck queue watchdog timer 0=system default, 1=disable (default: 1) (int)
parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
parm:           uapsd_disable:disable U-APSD functionality (default: Y) (bool)
parm:           bt_coex_active:enable wifi/bt co-exist (default: enable) (bool)
parm:           led_mode:0=system default, 1=On(RF On)/Off(RF Off), 2=blinking, 3=Off (default: 0) (int)
parm:           power_save:enable WiFi power management (default: disable) (bool)
parm:           power_level:default power save level (range from 1 - 5, default: 1) (int)
parm:           fw_monitor:firmware monitor - to debug FW (default: false - needs lots of memory) (bool)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/3.19.0-66-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     381EA511B7BC282E4E24C0E
depends:        
intree:         Y
vermagic:       3.19.0-66-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
signer:         Magrathea: Glacier signing key
sig_key:        A6:7F:A1:0F:B1:52:23:8E:81:45:C8:5E:D3:90:DE:D3:2B:0E:A5:43
sig_hashalgo:   sha512
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[iwldvm]
force_cam: Y

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[iwlwifi]
11n_disable: 0
amsdu_size_8K: 0
antenna_coupling: 0
bt_coex_active: Y
fw_monitor: N
fw_restart: Y
led_mode: 0
nvm_file: (null)
power_level: 0
power_save: N
swcrypto: 0
uapsd_disable: Y
wd_disable: 1

[cfg80211]
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x14e4:0x1698 (tg3)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x8086:0x4232 (iwlwifi)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"

##### dmesg #############################

[    8.886939] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    9.061573] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 8.83.5.1 build 33692 op_mode iwldvm
[    9.486385] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUG disabled
[    9.486389] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEBUGFS enabled
[    9.486391] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: CONFIG_IWLWIFI_DEVICE_TRACING enabled
[    9.486393] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) WiFi Link 5100 AGN, REV=0x54
[    9.486450] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[    9.622054] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-agn-rs'
[   22.670954] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   22.673930] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   22.771334] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Disabled
[   22.774310] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Radio type=0x1-0x2-0x0
[   24.274522] tg3 0000:08:00.0 eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex
[   24.274533] tg3 0000:08:00.0 eth0: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX
[   85.252213] tg3 0000:08:00.0 eth0: Link is down
[  318.237983] tg3 0000:08:00.0 eth0: Link is up at 100 Mbps, full duplex
[  318.237987] tg3 0000:08:00.0 eth0: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the right driver (`iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode` ) but it dosn't work under the 3.19 kernel version , You nedd to compile the `iwlwifi` Backported driver :

Install `build-essential` and `linux-headers` then download and compile the driver:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.19-rc1/backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.gz
tar xvf backports-3.19-rc1-1.tar.gz
cd backports-3.19-rc1-1
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

**Edit**

Downoad `iwlwifi-5000-ucode-8.83.5.1-1.tgz` from [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi)

```
wget https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi-5000-ucode-8.83.5.1-1.tgz
tar xvf iwlwifi-5000-ucode-8.83.5.1-1.tgz
cd iwlwifi-5000-ucode-8.83.5.1-1
cp iwlwifi-*.ucode /lib/firmware
```

Then recompile backport

Reboot and relaod driver:

```
modprobe -r iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
```

Comment: Thank you @GAD3R for your answer, every command completed without throwing errors but nothing changes.

Comment: I edit my answer

Comment: Thank you again GAD3R for your help, but not working yet.
Sorry @techraf. It won't happen again.
terdon I thought that after executing what GAD3R suggested something could have chaged in the wireless info. As you see I have little experience with linux